# iOSのバージョンでキーボード出現時にUITextFieldが自動で隠れないようにスクロールするようになったバージョンはありますか？

Tags: swift, ios, objective-c, uikit

iOSのバージョンでキーボード出現時にUITextFieldが自動で隠れないようにスクロールするようになったバージョンはありますか？

Objective-C時代に、自前で隠れないようにView（厳密にはUIScrollViewだったような?）を移動させてたら、急にiOS側のバージョンアップで2重にスクロールするようになり、自前のスクロール処理をはずした記憶があるような気がするのですが、iOS10, 11, 12ではそのような挙動は確認されませんでした。

どこかのバージョンで自動でスクロールするようになって、そしてまたどこかのバージョンで自動スクロールがなくなったりしたのでしょうか？　それとも記憶違いでしょうか？

（記憶はSwiftが世にでる2から3年ほど前の時代です）

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> iOSのバージョンでキーボード出現時にUITextFieldが自動で隠れないようにスクロールするようになったバージョンはありますか？

基本的にはないです。これまでのすべてのiOSのバージョンにおいて、ソフトウェアキーボードによってUITextFieldを含むビューの要素が隠れないようにするためには、ソフトウェアキーボードの表示・非表示を監視して、自分で要素を移動させるなどの処理を書く必要があります。

基本的に、と書いたのは例外があるからです。

例えばUITableViewControllerはセルがテキストフィールドや同等のコンポーネントを含む場合、キーボードを自動的に避けてくれる（自動的に隠れない位置にTableViewをスクロールさせる）機能があります。
（UITableViewではないです。UITableViewControllerです。）

おそらく、UITableViewControllerを使った画面を触っているときに、通常の画面と同じようにキーボードを避ける処理を書いたらUITableViewControllerの処理と重複した、ということではないでしょうか。